# Is there anyway to reduce the duplicate prerequisites pattern in GNU make?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

Current way is like this, which looks quite clumsy..

```
ex1_test : ex1.o ex1_test.o
    cc -o ex1_test ex1.o ex1_test.o
ex2_test : ex2.o ex2_test.o
    cc -o ex2_test ex2.o ex2_test.o
ex3_test : ex3.o ex3_test.o
    cc -o ex3_test ex3.o ex3_test.o
```

Is there a variable that I can use to represent the current target and reduce the duplicate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1, introduce automatic variables:

```
ex1_test : ex1.o ex1_test.o
    cc -o $@ $^
ex2_test : ex2.o ex2_test.o
    cc -o $@ $^
ex3_test : ex3.o ex3_test.o
    cc -o $@ $^
```

Step 2, realize that these rules all look the same, and replace them with a pattern rule:

```
ex%_test: ex%.o ex%_test.o
    cc -o $@ $^
```

Answer (score 2):

$@ and $^ are your friend. $@ is the target, and $^ the list of prerequisites.

```
ex1_test : ex1.o ex1_test.o
    cc -o $@ $^
```

There are more useful make variables in the GNU Make documentation in the [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) section.